# Discrete math- logical operations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

If a implies b is true, then does that mean (a and c) implies (b and c) is true?

I figured that the truth value of c doesn't matter but I am not exactly sure.

Comment: The second implication is only false if "a and c" is true and "b and c" is false. This means that a and c must be true and therefore b must be false. But in this case, the first implication is false as well. You can also verify this by cases (c true and c false)

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Math.SE! $c$ does somewhat matter. You know $a \implies b$ and you certainly know that $c \implies c$, so you have
$$
a \land c \implies a \implies b
$$
and in addition
$$
a \land c \implies c \implies c
$$
so in summary $a \land c \implies b \land c$.

---

You can do this using formal logic as well. $x \implies y$ is true iff whenever $x=1$ you also have $y = 1$. So assuming $a \land c = 1$ you have to prove $b \land c = 1$...